# how to extract text from html using beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I want to extract some words from this html like

```
<tr class="BgSilver" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
  <td align="right" style="width:75px;" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblRowNum" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">124</span>
  </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblAwardBasicNumber" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document">SP450017D0007</a></span>
   </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblDeliveryOrder" style="display:inline-block;width:175px;"><img alt="-spacer-" border="0" height="16" hspace="1" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16"/>0243 <br/><img alt="-spacer-" border="0" height="16" hspace="1" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16"/><span style="font-size: 9px;">» <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRec.aspx?contract=SP450017D0007&amp;dlv=0243&amp;cnt=" target="DIBBS" title="Delivery Order Package View">Delivery Order Package View</a></span></span>
   </td>
    <td align="right" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblDeliveryOrderCounter" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;"> </span>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblLastModPostingDate" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;">04-12-2018</span>
   </td>

</tr>
```

this is a section of the my code that generates the html above

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  from selenium import webdriver
  import urllib3
  import numpy as np
  import re

  from datetime import datetime, timedelta 


  containers = pagesoup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['BgWhite', 'BgSilver']})



                        for batch in containers:

                            for item in range(53)[2:]:



                                try:
                                    // batch is the html above
                                    print(batch)

                                    uid = "ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl"+str(item)+"_lblAwardBasicNumber"
                                    print("uid id ", uid)
                                    awardid = batch.find_all("span", text = re.compile("_lblAwardBasicNumber"))


                                    print("award id is")
                                    print(awardid)

                                except Exception as e:
                                    print(colorama.Fore.MAGENTA + "award error.."+ str(e) )
                                    # print(container1)

                                    continue


                    except Exception as e:
                        raise e
```

print (batch) is what produces the html above, I wanted to obtain this number SP450017D0007 from this

```
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblAwardBasicNumber" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document">SP450017D0007</a></span>
```

but awardid is outputing none. how can i extract SP450017D0007 ?

Comment: Extract `SP450017D0007` from where? If it is from the elements you have pasted at the bottom then why have you pasted the above portion. Please edit your question to make it look like a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

To get this text `SP450017D0007`, I used `pagesoup.find('a', text=True).text`.

Note:

You have the following extra lines in your code above that should be taken out

```
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib3
import numpy as np
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = '''
<tr class="BgSilver" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
  <td align="right" style="width:75px;" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblRowNum" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">124</span>
  </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblAwardBasicNumber" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document">SP450017D0007</a></span>
   </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblDeliveryOrder" style="display:inline-block;width:175px;"><img alt="-spacer-" border="0" height="16" hspace="1" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16"/>0243 <br/><img alt="-spacer-" border="0" height="16" hspace="1" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16"/><span style="font-size: 9px;">» <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRec.aspx?contract=SP450017D0007&amp;dlv=0243&amp;cnt=" target="DIBBS" title="Delivery Order Package View">Delivery Order Package View</a></span></span>
   </td>
    <td align="right" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblDeliveryOrderCounter" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;"> </span>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblLastModPostingDate" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;">04-12-2018</span>
   </td>

</tr>
'''

pagesoup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
containers = pagesoup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['BgWhite', 'BgSilver']})

for batch in containers:
    for item in range(53)[2:]:
        try:
            print(batch)
            uid = "ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl" + str(item) + "_lblAwardBasicNumber"
            print("uid id ", uid)
            awardid = pagesoup.find('a', text=True).text
            print("award id is")
            print(awardid)
            dateid = pagesoup.find('span', id='ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblLastModPostingDate').text
            print("date id is")
            print(dateid)

        except Exception as e:
            print(colorama.Fore.MAGENTA + "award error.." + str(e))
            # print(container1)
            continue
```

Output:

```
<tr class="BgSilver" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
<td align="right" style="width:75px;" valign="top">
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblRowNum" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">124</span>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblAwardBasicNumber" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/27FEB17/SP450017D0007.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document">SP450017D0007</a></span>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblDeliveryOrder" style="display:inline-block;width:175px;"><img alt="-spacer-" border="0" height="16" hspace="1" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16"/>0243 <br/><img alt="-spacer-" border="0" height="16" hspace="1" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16"/><span style="font-size: 9px;">» <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRec.aspx?contract=SP450017D0007&amp;dlv=0243&amp;cnt=" target="DIBBS" title="Delivery Order Package View">Delivery Order Package View</a></span></span>
</td>
<td align="right" valign="top">
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblDeliveryOrderCounter" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;"> </span>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblLastModPostingDate" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;">04-12-2018</span>
</td>
</tr>
uid id  ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl2_lblAwardBasicNumber
award id is
SP450017D0007
date id is
04-12-2018
```

Comment: I was hoping I will be able to use the same format to extract other numbers in html but the solution is specifically for field with a tag. How would you extract 04-12-2018 in the last span?

Comment: I edited my code to extract the date, but I'm still not sure if that is what you want. Can you clarify on "but the solution is specifically for field with a tag."?

Comment: I don't know what the id ( id='ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl26_lblLastModPostingDate') will always be. I only know it always ends with "lblLastModPostingDate" how can get the value with only the ending letters above?